# Change color text while the Background's SVG Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a background `SVG animation` that i created and have a text .
**Check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Norhan/vf9fzLuh/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- Background SVG -->
    <svg width="1500" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="background-svg">
        <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
        <g>
            <title>Background</title>
            <path fill="#fefefe" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" d=" m498.33967,-113.03246c99.6527,78.64871 -127.11402,258.15614 -190.68809,236.79926c-63.57406,-21.35688 -114.68809,-306.16174 -46.65269,-211.12362c68.0354,95.03812 137.68808,-104.32435 237.34078,-25.67564z" id="shap" stroke-opacity="0" fill-opacity="0.9" />
        </g>
    </svg>
    <!-- /Background SVG -->

    <div class="container">

        <!-- Intro -->
        <div id="intro">
            <p >Text</p>
            <h1 ><strong>Title Here</strong></h1>

        </div>
        <!-- /Intro -->


    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
color: #fff;
background-color: #f857a6;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.background-svg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.background-svg path {
    -webkit-animation: svgAnimate 20s infinite alternate linear;
    animation: svgAnimate 20s infinite alternate linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes svgAnimate {
to {
        d: path("m276.33967,389.03246c130.6527,-65.35129 -20.11402,367.15614 -190.68809,236.79926c-170.57407,-130.35688 -161.68809,-159.16174 -46.65269,-211.12362c115.0354,-51.96188 106.68808,39.67565 237.34078,-25.67564z");
    }
}
@keyframes svgAnimate {
    to {
        d: path("m276.33967,389.03246c130.6527,-65.35129 -20.11402,367.15614 -190.68809,236.79926c-170.57407,-130.35688 -161.68809,-159.16174 -46.65269,-211.12362c115.0354,-51.96188 106.68808,39.67565 237.34078,-25.67564z");
    }
}

/*====================*/


/* Intro Div */

#intro {

    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 60px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;

    margin-top: 7%;
}
.name {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
}

/*====================*/
```

I want to change the text color while the animation matches it and rest to the default color when it leaves .

**Any Help ?**

**Thanks In Advance**

**update**

Solved with another Example :
https://codepen.io/norhan22/pen/jwJvxw?editors=1100

Comment: Just the parts that overlap change colour? Or the whole text changes?  Have you considered the simpler option of putting a border around the text? https://jsfiddle.net/vf9fzLuh/3/

Comment: ya just the parts 
Your solution is pretty :)

Is there any way to chang the text color of the parts? ( not only border)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the CSS property `mix-blend-mode`.  It controls how an element blends its colours with the other contents of its parent element.

So, for example, if you set:

```
mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
```

on the text, you can make the text colour invert when it intersects with the moving blob.  To avoid the pink background colour messing with the colour also, we need to move that to an element that is not the `<svg>` or its parent (`<div class="content">`). SO I've just moved it to the `<body>` element for this example.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f857a6;
}
.content {
 color: #fff;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.background-svg {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -4;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.background-svg path {
 -webkit-animation: svgAnimate 25s infinite alternate linear;
 animation: svgAnimate 25s infinite alternate linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes svgAnimate {
to {
  d: path("m276.33967,389.03246c130.6527,-65.35129 -20.11402,367.15614 -190.68809,236.79926c-170.57407,-130.35688 -161.68809,-159.16174 -46.65269,-211.12362c115.0354,-51.96188 106.68808,39.67565 237.34078,-25.67564z");
 }
}
@keyframes svgAnimate {
 to {
  d: path("m276.33967,389.03246c130.6527,-65.35129 -20.11402,367.15614 -190.68809,236.79926c-170.57407,-130.35688 -161.68809,-159.16174 -46.65269,-211.12362c115.0354,-51.96188 106.68808,39.67565 237.34078,-25.67564z");
 }
}

/*====================*/


/* Intro Div */

#intro {
 /*
 background:#fff;
 color:#f857a6;
*/
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding: 60px;
 height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 /* box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.23);*/
 margin-top: 7%;
}
.name {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}

/*====================*/
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <!-- Background SVG -->
  <svg width="1500" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="background-svg">
   <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
   <g>
    <title>Background</title>
    <path fill="#fefefe" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" d=" m498.33967,-113.03246c99.6527,78.64871 -127.11402,258.15614 -190.68809,236.79926c-63.57406,-21.35688 -114.68809,-306.16174 -46.65269,-211.12362c68.0354,95.03812 137.68808,-104.32435 237.34078,-25.67564z" id="shap" stroke-opacity="0" fill-opacity="0.9" />
   </g>
  </svg>
  <!-- /Background SVG -->

  <div class="container">

   <!-- Intro -->
   <div id="intro" class="left-center">
    <p class="">Text</p>
    <h1 class="name display-3"><strong>Title Here</strong></h1>
    
   </div>
   <!-- /Intro -->

   <!-- Porfolio -->
   <div id="portfolio">

   </div>
   <!-- /Porfolio -->

   <!-- Contact Me -->
   <div id="contact">

   </div>
   <!-- /Contact Me -->
  </div>
 </div>
```

I believe this should work in all modern browsers except IE.  However your animation only works in Chrome now anyway.

Comment: Just can i change the black color to others ?
and why it not reverse the colors  ( the blend mode color text to pink ) ?

Comment: You can't directly set the colour that appears on overlap.  You would need to experiment with the text colour, the background colour, the blob colour, and the `mix-blend-mode` value to find the combination that produces the best combination for your needs. Only some of the modes will produce the effect your want. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode